# Facing Python Package version issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pandas

I am trying to run an old django project which was build on `python 3.6`.
Currently I am using `venv` with `python 3.10` & below is my list of dependencies

```
mysqlclient==1.3.13
arrow==0.12.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
pymongo==3.7.1
pytrends==4.4.0
Faker==0.9.1
newsapi-python==0.2.3
progressbar2==3.38.0
newspaper3k==0.2.7
requests==2.17.1
beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
selenium==3.14.0
lxml==4.2.5
pandas==0.23.4
langdetect==1.0.7
pyjwt==1.6.4
msgpack==0.5.6
bpython==0.17.1
xlsxWriter==1.1.1
feedparser==5.2.1
querystring-parser==1.2.3
google_images_download==2.5.0
xlrd==1.2.0
algoliasearch==2.0.4
PyMySQL==0.9.3
fuzzywuzzy==0.17.0
python-levenshtein==0.12.0
firebase-admin==4.3.0
```

Can any one suggest me package version for smooth project run?

Comment: What issue do you have? If that is a list of dependencies, can you not feed that into `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: Are you just trying to *run* the Django project, or do you want to upgrade it to a new Django/Python version?

Comment: @JonSG its in requirements.txt file.

Comment: @9769953 yes, i want to upgrade

Comment: Try first with a requirements.txt file as above, but without any version constraints. That should give you the latests versions (and presumably you use the latest Django version as well). From there, see what works, and otherwise try a downgrade of that package. If it all works, you can fix the versions to what is installed.

Comment: Be aware that some packages may have gone out of data, and may not have been updated for years, so even the most recent version might not work with newer versions of Django. In that case, you'll have to remove that package entirely, or find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to this URL (https://pypi.org/search/?q=&o=&c=Programming+Language+%3A%3A+Python+%3A%3A+3.10 - I have already made the selection to show `Python 3.10` compatible packages) and in the search-bar (top-left) enter the package (for example `mysqlclient`). This will give you a list of compatible versions of that specific package (`mysqlclient 2.1.1`).
I don't know any other easy approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Python version compatibility checkers available, including:

**

- check-python-versions

** - This tool checks the packages in your requirements file against a specified Python version.

**

- checkmyreqs

** - This tool checks the packages in your requirements file against the Python versions that they are known to be compatible with.

**

- compatibility

** - This tool checks whether the running Python interpreter version is supported by a given package.